# GIT with SSL on Mavericks (error -9824)

Tags: git, ssl

On OS X Maverick.

I have p12 file for connect to sever.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out test.key
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -nodes -nokeys -out test.cert
```

In git config i add:

```
[http]
    sslCert = ~/keys/test.cert
    sslKey = ~/keys/test.key
```

After i try get sources

```
git pull
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.***.com/gitweb/***.git': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to git.***.com:-9824
```

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install curl - with-darwinssl
brew install git - with-curl-brewed
```

In config

```
[http]
    sslCert = <user_name_from_cert>
```

And use
`/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.0/bin/git pull`
or
    `/usr/local/opt/git/bin/git pull`

Answer (score 0):

Check which SSL protocols the server you are trying to connect to supports by using this website: [ssllabs.com/ssltest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html)

Then force that protocol in the git config using:

`git config http.sslVersion [sslv2|sslv3|tlsv1|tlsv1.0|tlsv1.1|tlsv1.2|tlsv1.3]`

Read through the rest of the `git config http.XXX` parameters at the [official git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslVersion), you may be missing something else:

```
git config http.sslBackend openssl
git config http.sslVersion tlsv1.0
git config http.sslVerify false
```